# guidance and help required on improving open source ML/Data Mining Libraries

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-transformation

We would like to crawl a bunch of websites for specific information like the about us,company,technology pages of start-ups and enable sharing it across a social network which  my organization is developing.

1) Crawling such websites is the first challenge. We tried using Crawler4j and bolierpipe which are openly available. Crawler4j does not remove the bolierplate content and it confuses our summarization algorithm due to presence of unstructured text commonly generated by it after crawling any of start-up websites. Bolierpipe(created to crawl news sites) on the the other hand performs better but has its limitations since its not accurate when removing all bolierplate content(it uses some advanced data mining algorithm which is currently beyond our expertise).

2) Our second challenge is text Summarization. We are currently using Classifier4j(Openly available) which again is not accurate to the levels or Production Quality. Firstly since the data is unstructured (since its generated after crawling a webpage and not a normal document) it gets confused with sentences(We are also not sure how the internal algo treats the raw data). Also about summarizing webpages just like facebook summarizes using the meta content in a HTML page we dont have that opportunity since most of start-ups in FMCG sector don't use meta tags in their webpages.I understand we can provide training data but this is beyond the scope of our current expertise. I tried using other libraries like Dragon toolkit (which is a bit old since it was written in 2008) but getting them to work is a challenge.

Any direction to a new library or technical guidance as to what ML algorithm to use and attempt to build will be greatly helpful.

Comment: [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is an excellent tool for webcrawling. For the learning part, since you are mainly dealing with text, you probably want to use Naive Bayes and/or linear SVM (classification), low-rank approximations (recommender systems) and word-vector embeddings.

Answer (score 0):

generalised ML solutions to problems like summarisation just do not work very well outside of very sophisticated supporting machinery.

Consider "crawling" a two part operation of collecting pages and then turning them into plain text and meta-data. Boilerpipe is very decent. It has many templates for content extraction. Consider using a different template for each page type. How are you determining if you are indeed on the about us page? The company page? The product page? Can you translate your criteria directly to google or bing queries restricted to a URL? If so, you could save yourself oodles of time working with your own crawlers.

Regarding summarisation, I'd advise abandoning a one-for-all solution. A summarisation is supposed to provide enough information to understand what may be on the page, under some length constraint (say 100 words). For many company pages that's exactly what the first paragraph does. When the first paragraph is not enough, consider the structure of the information on the page and think about what may make a good solution, then look for the technical tooling to solve it.

In summary, I'd suggest first exhausting the low hanging fruit and then dealing with the remainder which will probably be smaller than you expect. Hope that helps. PM me if you'd like to have a more informed discussion.

Comment: 1) Why would i need sophisticated machinery. Are you referring to using Map-Reduce on a cluster. Can you be more detailed about this.
2) I am trying your suggestion of using different bolierpipe templates for different web pages as testing exercise. One more question is how to figure it out at run time what kind of template would give the best results.
3) We are doing it the same way (using google to land on the about-us and similar pages). But there are ways to determine (only 50% of the times) that we are "actually" on the about-us page. I am unable to PM on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please *merge* your accounts. You can find out how in our [help]. Then you will be able to comment on your own thread.